# Problems with Thunderbird line breaks

Tags: line-breaks, thunderbird, plaintext

When composing a new mail in Mozilla Thunderbird, the lines will break after 72 characters:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
deserunt dicta dignissimos est et illo ipsam iure libero magnam maiores
maxime, natus necessitatibus nesciunt nostrum, perspiciatis, tenetur
velit! Consequatur, perspiciatis!
```

Despite the fact, that 4 lines are displayed, this is still a single line.

This is especially annoying, when code is included.

When I receive such a mail, the text is formatted correctly as a single line. (Good!)

However, when I forward, or reply the mail, the lines will break:

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
> deserunt dicta dignissimos est et illo ipsam iure libero magnam maiores
> maxime, natus necessitatibus nesciunt nostrum, perspiciatis, tenetur
> velit! Consequatur, perspiciatis!
```

Now the same text is distributed over 4 lines.

Is there any chance to change this silly behavior?

What I want is simple:

1. Composing: display text as entered.
2. Forwarding / replying: add extra chars to indicate forwarded / replied portion, but do not break the lines.

Thunderbird version: 24.6.0, OS: Ubuntu

Comment: A very similar question is asked and answered at superuser.com
http://superuser.com/questions/378184/tell-thunderbird-not-to-truncate-or-wrap-lines-when-sending-email

Answer (score 1):

[Stefan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554357/problems-with-thunderbird-line-breaks#comment66072999_35554357) points to [a similar question on superuser](https://superuser.com/q/378184/260809).
For me, the solution in [Joost's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/378184/tell-thunderbird-not-to-truncate-or-wrap-lines-when-sending-email#comment786914_378238) to the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/378238/260809) there works: Setting

```
mailnews.wraplength → 0
```

in the config editor (Edit → Preferences → Advanced →  General → Config Editor...).